# How to get time in 12hr format from a long value in java

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I have a long value which have values as given bellow,

e.g.

```
timeInLong = 1000 (which means 10:00 AM)
timeInLong = 1337 (which means 01:37 PM)
```

I need a smart way to convert above types of values and get time as 10:00AM and 01:37PM in `string` format.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: What does the long value represent? the first two digits is the hour, the next two is minutes? how do you then represent 07:45AM ? And why use long for that?
But if you represent time like this, then everything > 1200 is PM, rest AM. %100 gives you minutes; / 100 gives you hours. And for PM times deduct 1200 before calculating hours and minutes

Answer (score 4):

Code -

```
Long timeInLong = 1000l;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(Long.toString(timeInLong));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(date));
```

Result -

> 10:00 AM

Comment: Okay, that looks somewhat nicer than my solution :)

Comment: The second format string should be `hh:mm a`, not `HH:mm a` - note that `hh` is 12-hour clock, `HH` is 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat readerFormat = "HHmm";
SimpleDateFormat writerFormat = "hh:mma";

Date date = readerFormat.parse(Long.toString(timeInLong));
String toPrint = writerFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatA = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmm");
SimpleDateFormat formatB = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date intermediate = formatA.parse(String.valueOf(1337));
String result = formatB.format(intermediate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int timeInLong = 1337;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeInLong % 100);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeInLong / 100);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a", Locale.US).format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams too easy, but what about:

```
int hours = timeInLong / 100;
int minutes = timeInLong % 100;
boolean isPM = false;

if (hours > 12) {
   isPM = true
} 

if (hours > 13) {
   hours -= 12;
}
String result = String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hours, minutes, (isPM ? "PM" : "AM"));
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative and efficient oneliner if you want to avoid the SimpleDateFormat import:

```
String toTimeString(long time) {
    return ((time < 1300) ? time / 100 : time / 100 - 12)
         + ":" + time % 100
         + ((time < 1200) ? " AM" : " PM");
}
```